# Is the total momentum of the ground and a ball that bounces vertically up the ground conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

The distance that a ball reaches after it bounce is less than the height from which it was dropped. So 
$$m_1v_1 + m_2v_2 \neq m_1v_1' + m_2v_2'$$ Where:

- $m_2$ is mass of earth
- $v_2$ is initial velocity of earth
- $v_2'$ final velocity of earth

Is momentum not conserved in this scenario?

Comment: Momentum is conserved as far as there are not external forces. If consider the ball as your system, part of its momentum will go to the molecules of air and ground that it hits.

Comment: The equation should have an equal sign, not a not-equal sign.  Kinetic plus potential energy might not be conserved, but momentum is.

Answer (score 2):

The  momentum of the ball is not conserved. The total momentum of the ball and earth is conserved.

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly concluded that the ball had lost some speed on the rebound, but you've incorrectly assumed that the speed of the earth had not changed as a result of the impact.

Of course, even if you set out to measure the change of the speed of the earth, no instrument would allow you to do so with a required precision. But even if you could make such measurement, it would not tell you much, since, at any given moment, the earth experiences billions of impacts and the change of its speed due to the impact of your ball would be lost in the resulting noise.

So, this is not the right setup for proving or disproving the law of the conservation of momentum - it would be much better to use two balls or other objects of comparable masses.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sentence is a non-sequitur. The fact that the ball has not rebounded to its initial height does not mean that overall momentum is lost. To see the fault in the logic, consider what happens if you replace the bouncing ball with a sack of potatoes- what happens to its momentum when it hits the ground?

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal scenario,take ball and earth as the system then there would be no external forces so linear momentum of the system is conserved.

In real scenario,air drag is the net external force which reduces the linear momentum of earth_ball system.